# error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector in a kernel

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, opencl

I'm working with the following code:

```
__kernel                                                
void addround(__global int **A, __global int *B, int kSize, int kRound, int kNb)                                
{                   
  for (int i=0;i<kSize;i++){                            
     for (int j=0;j<kSize;j++){                     
        A[j][i]+=B[kRound*kNb*kSize+i*kNb+j];    
       }                        
   }                                                    
}
```

And this line `A[j][i]+=B[kRound*kNb*kSize+i*kNb+j];` is marking an error, saying that it's not an array, pointer, or vector when I try to compile. I think the problem might have to do with the double pointer A, but I fail to see how. Any suggestions?

Comment: Guess: Its the unqualified middle.  Does `__global int * __global *A` make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double pointers do not exist in OpenCL as an input/output. Since the pointers are not allowed to travel from CPU <-> GPU.

You have to manually address matrixes, this means:

```
__kernel                                                
void addround(__global int *A, __global int *B, int kSize, int kRound, int kNb)                                
{                   
  for (int i=0;i<kSize;i++){                            
     for (int j=0;j<kSize;j++){                     
        A[j+i*kSize]+=B[kRound*kNb*kSize+i*kNb+j];    
       }                        
   }                                                    
}
```

NOTE: Just a small remark, the kernel code you are using is completely inefficient, it will take even longer than the CPU plain version. I just did the minimal changes to solve your problem, thats all.

Comment: Thank you. I only started learning OpenCL recently; what would you do to make this code more efficient?

Comment: OpenCL is parallel computing, you should split the job in pieces and make each work-item work on one piece. Instead you are running a double for loop for each work-item. In fact, you don't even use get_global_id(), which HAS to be used in all the OpenCL kernels. Please address any tutorial, since your code has many deep design flaws that you are missing out that I can't explain in this comment. Your code will simply run like 100 times slower than CPU as it is now.